# Laravel - Auth getting stuck on reading session file

Tags: php, laravel, session

hope you're good

I was trying to add a profile table to my Laravel 5.6 project, and I'm also using the spatie\Laravel-Permission package. It was working fine, but after I ran some migrations (that have nothing to do with users), it started failing on the login. The curious thing is that, if I register a new user, it gets logged in properly, but never with the /login route (I'm using the Laravel's Auth scaffolding).

After debugging the project, I came up with the method that's failing, it's something reading the sessions:

```
MyProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php

<?php
namespace Illuminate\Filesystem;

use ErrorException;
use FilesystemIterator;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException;

class Filesystem{
    // ...
    public function get($path, $lock = false)
    {
        if ($this->isFile($path)) {
            return $lock ? $this->sharedGet($path) : file_get_contents($path); // <-- The failing line
        }

        throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist at path {$path}");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Once it gets to that line, the debugger stops, the browser doesnt get a response, the dd() function does not get triggered... I also tried to debug the sharedGet($path) method, and it returns the value, but back to the method above, it stops.

Also, the php_error.log file gets absurdly increased on every request (up to 500MB/request), so much that none of the editors I use can open it (SublimeText, NetBeans).

My thoughts are that apache may be running out of memory when reading the files, but the session file barely weights 1k, so it wouldn't make much sense.

Can someone throw any clue? Thanks

--EDIT:

I tried installing a fresh laravel proyect with only the Auth module and the spatie/laravel-permission package, and I noticed the same behaviour: it registers and logs users, but after logging it out, I'm no longer able to log in with any user.

Comment: you could try and open the file using notepad. Also, one issue could be the path of the session or the ability of laravel to access it.

Comment: is your `/tmp` full?

Comment: use commandline to read the log: `less php_error.log` or `more php_error.log` or `tail -n 200 php_error.log`.

Comment: @hungrykoala the path is fine, it also gets to store the content in a variable. After returning it is when it gets stuck

Comment: @Ohgodwhy there is space enough, I have 100GB free

Comment: @Kyslik I'm on Windows, the powershell tool doesn't have less or tail commands. The cat command took more than 30 minutes to read the whole file, and it ran out of memory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someonw gets to the same error:

I could manage to solve this by backing up all my projects/databases and reinstalling wampserver with the last version of php (by the moment of this answer, it is 7.2.4) and reinstalling Laravel (luckily the proyect was barely starting), which only updated vlucas/phpdotenv package from 2.4.0 to 2.5.0 and phpunittest.

Whith this update now I can log in users normally, now let's see if it works as it should with spatie/laravel-permission package and the profile table I need to add.